# How to map a list of component in Entity Framework 5?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm a NHibernate user and NHibernate allows me to create a very fine-grained model.
I'm porting an application from NHibernate to Entity Framework.

NHibernate allows me to define things like:

```
public class User : DomainEntity
{
    public virtual Name Name { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<LogonInformation> LogonInformations { get; set; }
}

public class Name
{
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class LogonInformation
{
    public virtual string Ip { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Where Name and LogonInformation are mapped as < componentes >.
In special case,when NHibernate is creating the database, creates the UserId in LogonInformation table.
How can I do this using EntityFramework 5? 
I've tried using the Complex Types but it does not seems to work since I still get the following exception:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> \tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType
>   'LogonInformation' has no key defined. Define the key for this
>   EntityType.
>
> \tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet
>   'LogonInformations' is based on type 'LogonInformation' that has no
>   keys defined.

Answer (score 0):

Your exception is complaining about `LogonInformation` not having a primary key. In order to establish a primary key you add the attribute `Key` to the property you want to be the primary key, for instance, if `Ip` is your primary key, your code would be:

```
public class LogonInformation
{
    [Key]
    public virtual string Ip { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**
If you can't change `LogonInformation` you can set its primary key with Fluent-API (I don't like this way but it could solve your problem). In order to do that, you need to override the `OnModelCreating` method in your context like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<LogonInformation>().HasKey(logInfo => logInfo.Ip);
}
```

Comment: Can't I just tell EF to add the UserId column during the "boot" time as NHibernate does? I can't change the LogonInformation class.

Comment: @cidico: I don't know NHibernate, but in EF Code-First the way you have to set a primary key property is rather naming it as `Id` or adding the `Key` attribute.

Comment: @cidico: I edited my answer, check it and let me know if that's what you are looking for ;)

Comment: Sorry for the delay! Well, it's something like this, but I can't use the Ip property as my key (because it will repeat sometimes). What I need to do is just the same thing as map a IList<string>. It's a one-to-many and I need to add the Id from the parent. The same way as I can't add an Id property to the string type. I guess that EF does not supports it. :(